# Не игнорируется перевод строки в return

Tags: javascript

Почему второй `console.log` возвращает `undefined`?
Почему перевод строки не игнорируется? По идее, он должен был возвратить `object`.

```
"use strict";
function foo() {
    return {
        a: 1
    };
};

function foo1() {
    return
    { b: 1 };
};

console.log(foo()); //object
console.log(foo1()); //undefined
```

Comment: Он должен вернуть то, что находится начинается на той же строке, что и `return` в данном случае написано `верни пустоту` а дальше  то, что после `return` не выполнится..то есть по факту у вас написано `function foo1(){
    return;
};`  и там хоть объект, хоть число, хоть строка

Comment: $a = 5+
//перевод строки
2;
alert($a);

тут же игнорируется

Comment: А причем тут сложение и оператор `return` ?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  Это понятно что он пустоту возвращает.Но почему так, ведь когда учишь js говорится же что пробелы и переводы строк игнорируются.Я понимаю это что и в return и в любом другом действие это правило действует.Я так понял это bug

Comment: Это не баг. Это [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9).

Comment: @D-side  Спасибо.Я реально не подразумевал что есть такая чепуха.Надеюсь в дальнейшем они исправят

Comment: Это вряд ли. Обратная совместимость укусит за ж... м-м... неважно, за что.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan не создавайте объектов в `return`-e, и не будет вам никакой "чепухи". Точка с запятой после объявления функции, кстати, не нужна.

Comment: @Regent   в return-e  объекты не создаются

Comment: на самом деле `{ b: 1 }` расценивается как блок кода с меткой `b`, а не объект

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Во втором случае

```
return 
{ b: 1 };
```

то же самое что и

```
return;
{ b: 1 };
```

В итоге у вас `return` без аргументов и функция возвращает `undefined`.

[Подробнее](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9)

Comment: Чо он сам ставит ; ? Или это bug ? где можно почитать про эту фигню? Извиняюсь за выражение

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Просто return в данном случае не имеет аргументов так как возвращает только то что находится с ним на одной строке. Хотя могу предположить что движок добавляет там `;` во избежание ошибок в некоторых случаях, но это только предположение

Comment: Добавь ссылку к ответу и закроем тему http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9. Спасибо